# I'm getting an error creating a AWS AppSync Authenticated DataSource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync, aws-serverless

I working through the [Build On Serverless|S2 E4 video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_LpIw32MwZU&feature=youtu.be) and I've gotten to the point of creating an authenticated HTTP datasource using the AWS CLI.  I'm getting this error.

```
Parameter validation failed:
  Unknown parameter in httpConfig: "authorizationConfig", must be one of: endpoint
```

I think I'm using the same information provided in the video, repository and gist, updated for my own aws account.  It seems like it's some kind of formatting or missing information error, but, I'm just not seeing the problem.

When I remove the "authorizationConfig" property from the state-machine-datasource.json the command works.

I've reviewed the code against the information in the video as well as [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/appsync/create-data-source.html) and examples [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/invoke-aws-services-directly-from-aws-appsync/) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDataSource.html) provided by aws

This is the command I'm running.

```sh
aws appsync create-data-source --api-id {my app sync app id} --name ProcessBookingStateMachine 
--type HTTP --http-config file://src/backend/booking/state-machine-datasource.json 
--service-role-arn arn:aws:iam::{my account}:role/AppSyncProcessBookingState  --profile default
```

This is my state-machine-datasource.json:

```
{
    "endpoint": "https://states.us-east-2.amazonaws.com",
    "authorizationConfig": {
        "authorizationType": "AWS_IAM",
        "awsIamConfig": {
            "signingRegion": "us-east-2",
            "signingServiceName": "states"
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce your issue running the exact same command. In what region are you running your AppSync API? Would you be able to add `--debug` to your command and send me a request id so I can help you troubleshoot. i.e `aws --debug appsync create-data-source`

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I will do a run with --debug and also try a different region.  I won't be able to try it until this evening though.  Sorry.

Comment: @Tinou -- Thank you.  Your advice about using --debug was very good.  It led me to the python script used to validate the parameters.  Even though it wasn't explicitly spelled out what it was looking for I realized the definition of the parameters was probably old which led me to the version.

Unfortunately for me it was simply that I needed to upgrade my aws cli to the latest version.  I should have thought of that.  :( Thanks again for taking the time to answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to update my aws cli to the latest version.  The authenticated http datasource is something fairly new I guess.